# Application of mean value theorem (bounded derivative)

Tags: real-analysis

Im asked to show $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$ if $|f'(x)|\le M$ $x \in I$ and $f$ is continuous on $I$. I doubt this right as I'm not quite sure what it's asking.

Mean Value Theorem gives 
$$
f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(x-y) \implies |f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)(x-y)| = |f'(c)||x-y|
$$
Since $c\in I \implies |f'(c)|\le M$
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)||x-y| \le M|x-y|
$$

Which doesn't seem difficult enough so I think I've misunderstood the question. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What you have done is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with that.

I prefer a more direct approach: 
If $x, y \in I$ and if $x < y$, then
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x-y|\sup_{x < t < y}|f'(t)| \leq |x-y|M
$$
by assumption.

Comment: Yes that is more clear, I was going to add let M = sup |f'(x)| but since they define M already I decided not too.